# Random Number Generator in range in Discord js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm trying to make a command for my Discord bot that returns a random number in a range but for example in range 20 to 40 it always returns a number less than 20.

Here is my code:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'losowanie',
  description: 'losowy numer',
  execute(message, args, cmd, client, Discord) {
    const splited = message.content.trim().split(' ');
    const min = splited[1];
    const max = splited[2];
    if (!min) {
      message.channel.send(`brak wartosci minimalnej`);
      return;
    }
    if (!max) {
      message.channel.send(`brak wartosci maksymalnej`);
      return;
    }
    if (isNaN(min)) {
      message.channel.send(`wartośc minimalna musi być liczbą`);
      return;
    }
    if (isNaN(max)) {
      message.channel.send(`wartośc maksymalna musi być liczbą`);
      return;
    }
    if (min >= max) {
      message.channel.send(
        `wartość minimalna nie może być wieksza/równia aniżeli maksymalna`,
      );
      return;
    }

    message.channel.send(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `min` and `max` are strings.

`Math.random()` returns a number less than one, then you multiply it by 20 (`max-min`), it is now a number between 0 and 20. But... when you want to add the `min` value, which is a string in your case, JavaScript will concatenate instead, as it's not a number, so it will convert that random number between 0 and 20 to a string and add the string `"20"` to its end like in this example:

```js
const min = '20'
const max = '40'
const random = Math.random()

console.log({
  'max-min': max - min,
  'Math.random()*(max-min)': random * (max - min),
  'Math.random()*(max-min)+min': random * (max - min) + min
})
```

You need to convert the min and max values to numbers:

```js
const min = Number(splited[1])
const max = Number(splited[2])

// OR

const min = parseInt(splited[1], 10)
const max = parseInt(splited[2], 10)
```

Both will work fine.

```js
const min = Number('20')
const max = Number('40')

console.log(Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min)+min))
```